# cant delete image from storage laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, delete-file, public-method

hello everybody im trying to delete an image from local storage with this function but it returns

> Call to a member function delete() on string

which is right because when I use `dd(destination);` this is the result:

```
public/imagen/1634302328.jpg
```

is there a way to convert that string into a route path or other solution to delete an image from storage? thanks

this is my function:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {   
 
        $autoridad = Autoridad::find($id);
        $destination = 'public/imagen/'.$autoridad->imagen;
        if(File::exists($destination)){
            File::delete($destination);
        }
        $destination->delete();
        return redirect()->route('autoridades.index');
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant `$autoridad->delete()` instead of `$destination->delete()`. You assigned `$destination` to the string location of the image. That is why it does not allow you to call `delete()` on it.

Comment: if i do that,  the data is deleted from de data base but the image still remains in the storage. i think the problem in that laravel can´t convert the string wich contains the path to the image ("public/imagen/1634302328.jpg ")

Comment: Be sure to check whether the file actually can be found. You could add an `else { echo "File not found " . $destination; }

Comment: thanks you where right, laravel can not find the file. now i must look more information why is this happening

Comment: You could try to use the `public_path` helper to find the fully qualified path (absolute) to the file you are referring to. (docs https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-public-path)

Comment: Thank you very much!!! it worked, using a public path and unlink() instead delete();